# Why is Julia's Infiltrator package scrambling my REPL input?

Tags: debugging, julia, read-eval-print-loop

I am using Visual Studio Code with the Julia plugin. Regular debugging is impossibly slow, so I a tried to use the package `Infiltrator.jl`. I insert `@infiltrate` where I want execution to stop, just like a breakpoint and then start the REPL. Execution indeed stops there and the REPL prompt changes to yellow `infil>`. So far so good, but when I type something the letters get scrambled, sometimes when I hit Enter and sometimes even before that. It happens before my eyes. After two or three attempts the REPL prompt changes back to green `julia>` and the REPL freezes.

Anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [readme](https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Infiltrator.jl):

> Running code that ends up triggering the `@infiltrate` REPL mode via inline evaluation in VSCode or Juno can cause issues, so it's recommended to always use the REPL directly.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. What I did was insert the line with ```@infiltrate``` in a function and run the whole program in the VSCode REPL. The function is in a module different from the one I ran the REPL from (the main program, that prepares the data and calls the function that is creating problems). I thought I was Ok because I was not triggering the REPL mode, I was in REPL mode from the beginning. Am I wrong? What should I do differently?

Comment: "and run the whole program in the VSCode REPL" --  by just typing the entry point into the REPL prompt? That should work fine and is inconsistent with the failure mode described here.

Comment: Sorry, I am just a beginner and some things are over my head. When I said "run the whole program in the VSCode REPL" I meant clicking on a triangle on the upper part of the screen. When I hover with the mouse over it a pop-up says "Julia: Execute active file in REPL". I do not know what you mean by "just typing the entry point into the REPL prompt". I would like to try that.

Comment: Ah, I can see where the confusion is coming from. The Infiltrator readme means "literally type your code into the REPL and hit enter", so it could be something as simple as `julia> main()`, but of course I don't know how your code is structured.